# Swift Delete User from Firestore and Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Inside my app the `user` should be able to delete the account. I am struggling to get that done, as I have to delete from database and also from authentication.

I thought I can `deleteFromAuthentication` first and after that I `deleteEntryFromDatabase`. Theses are both of the functions:

```
//MARK: deleteUserFromDatabase
static func deleteUserEntryFromDatabase(oldUserId: String, finished: @escaping (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document(oldUserId).delete() { err in
            if err != nil {
                Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: err!.localizedDescription)
                finished(false)
            } else {
                finished(true)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

//MARK: deleteUserFromAuthentication
static func deleteUserFromAuthentication(finished: @escaping (_ done: Bool, _ hasToReauthenticate: Bool) -> Void) {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    user?.delete { err in
        if err != nil {
            if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: err!._code) {
                switch errCode {
                    case .requiresRecentLogin:
                        finished(true, true)
                default:
                 Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: err!.localizedDescription)
                    finished(false, false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            finished(true, false)
        }
    }
}
```

**How I use them:**

```
func deleteAccount() {
    var uid = ""
    if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
        uid = defaults.getUid()!
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
    
    DataHandler.deleteUserFromAuthentication { (finished, hasToReauthenticate) in
        if finished {
            if hasToReauthenticate {
                self.showReauthenticationAlert()
            } else {
                DataHandler.deleteUserEntryFromDatabase(oldUserId: uid) { (finished) in
                    if finished {
                        let firstLaunchVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstLaunchVC")
                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(firstLaunchVC, animated: false)
                        
                        if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
                            defaults.removePersistentDomain(forName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey)
                            defaults.synchronize()
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.loadingFailed()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.loadingFailed()
        }
    }
}
```

However this is not working as I get the error `insufficient permissions`. I thought I can do this workaround with `signInAnonymously` but apparently this is not working.

These are my `Cloud-Firestore-Rules`:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out here?  I hope everything is clear, let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this:

1. In the client-side code: first delete the user's document from the database, and only then delete their account. So the order is exactly the opposite of how you do it now, because there's no secure way to delete the account from the client once the account is deleted. I.e. if you make your current approach work, anyone can delete anyone else's user document, which is a big security risk.
2. Create a Cloud Function that deletes the user's document when their [account is deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion).

Comment: The second option suits better in my case. Could you elaborate on that ?

Comment: That's a bit beyond what is reasonable here. The page I linked has an example of how to trigger a Cloud Function upon user deletion. In that code you can then delete the user's document using the Admin SDK. I recommend giving it a try using the documentation and the many tutorials out there. If you get stuck after trying it, I recommend posting a question with the [minimal code that reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the right Swift Syntax? Cant find anything on this

Comment: That's because Cloud Functions are written in Node.js, and run on Google's servers. I answered as much on [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172596/swift-firebase-trigger-cloud-function-on-delete).