# Swift Firebase trigger Cloud Function on delete

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I would like to use the [on delete trigger function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) inside my project where I first delete the user from authentication and after that delete the user from the database.

In the provided link is a example, but I can not make it work in Swift. Let's say I can make it work, can I call something like this? Or is `Auth.auth().currentUser` not available anymore? And is there some workaround for that?

```
Auth.user.onDelete() { 
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    db.collection("users").document(user).delete() { err in
        if err != nil {
            Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Fehler", description: err!.localizedDescription)
            finished(false)
        } else {
            finished(true)
        }
    }
}
```

I know I could delete the user from the database first and from authentication afterwards but that is not quite fitting for my use-case. Can anyone help me out here? Also, let me know if anything is unclear and if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be confusing a few thing here.

Cloud Functions are written in Node.js, and run on Google servers - which allows them to respond to events happening in your Firebase projects. You can't respond to all those same events, such as a user account being deleted, in your client-side Swift code. So while it is perfectly feasible to use Cloud Functions to delete a document from Cloud Firestore in response to a user account being deleted from Firebase Authentication, you can't do this in your client-side Swift code.

What you can do in your Swift code, is delete the currently logged in user's account, and delete their document from Firestore. The typical order to do that in is to first delete the document, and only then delete the account, as deleting the document probably/should require the user to still exist and be authentication.

It'd be something like:

```
db.collection("cities").document("DC").delete() { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error removing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully removed!")
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    
        user?.delete { error in
          if let error = error {
            // An error happened.
          } else {
            // Account deleted.
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is mostly 1:1 copied from the document on [deleting data from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) and [deleting a user from Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Comment: Definitely got confused there... Ok, guess I have to change my flow then. Thanks for your explanation and help!